# How to style Swift Charts like Apple does?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

70 year old newbie here.
I am attempting to integrate a chart within my Mac app, and using Swift Charts (Apple's).
It's relatively easy to make a chart. The problem is the default charts look different to Apple's charts and are missing key elements that Apple uses.

Example:
[image: Storage Chart]
Apples charts generaly have

- A thin white separator between the elements
- Nice Rounded corners on the top and bottom
- Subtle internal shadow

I wrote the code:

```
struct BarChart: View {
    var body: some View {
        GroupBox {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("This is the label")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
            Chart(data) { item in
                BarMark(
                    x: .value("% ", item.count)
                    
                ) 
                .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Data:", item.usage))
            }
            .chartXAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: .automatic(desiredCount: 0))
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3))

        }
    }
}
```

But it looks like:
[image]

Any idea how I can add:

- A thin white separator between the elements
- Nice Rounded corners on the top and bottom
- Subtle internal shadow

Comment: I don't see a "subtle internal shadow". Do you mean the rectangular region surrounding the chart, with a slightly darker grey fill?

Comment: No, that’s the groupbox. I’m talking about the very subtle one inside the bar. More visible on the grey section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage chart in the System Preferences app probably isn't implemented with SwiftUI Charts framework. The chart has been looking this way since ages ago. I'd assume it doesn't use SwiftUI at all.

Anyway, the corner radius can be created with [`clipShape`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chartcontent/clipshape(_:style:)), but rather than applying it on the `Chart`, you should apply it on the `BarMark`s. Use the indices of your data source to determine which corners to round.

```
.clipShape(clipShape(forIndex: i))

...

func clipShape(forIndex i: Int) -> UnevenRoundedRectangle {
    if i == 0 {
        return UnevenRoundedRectangle(topLeadingRadius: 5, bottomLeadingRadius: 5)
    } else if i == data.count - 1 {
        return UnevenRoundedRectangle(bottomTrailingRadius: 5, topTrailingRadius: 5)
    } else {
        return UnevenRoundedRectangle()
    }
}
```

The separators can be created with transparent `BarMark`s that have a very small `x` value.

```
BarMark(...) // the actual bar mark for your data

if i != data.count - 1 {
    BarMark(x: .value("Separator", 0.1))
        .foregroundStyle(.clear)
}
```

The shadow is the hardest part. There is no such API to add an inner shadow, only on the top edge. In fact, SwiftUI charts doesn't seem to support `ShapeStyle`s that have shadows at all. For example, using `chartForegroundStyleScale` like this does not create any shadow at all.

```
.chartForegroundStyleScale([
    "Category 1": Color.red.shadow(.inner(radius: 5)),
    "Category 2": Color.green.shadow(.inner(radius: 5)),
    "Category 3": Color.yellow.shadow(.inner(radius: 5)),
])
```

The only way I can think of is to nudge a blurred `RectangleMark` around. This creates a something quite similar, but not exactly.

```
RectangleMark(yEnd: 3)
    .foregroundStyle(.black.opacity(0.34))
    .blur(radius: 1)
    // this inset is needed
    // or else the "shadow" extends beyond the rounded rectangles
    .clipShape(Rectangle().inset(by: 1))
    .offset(y: -1)
```

Here is the full code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let data = [
        Foo(width: 3, type: .one),
        Foo(width: 4, type: .two),
        Foo(width: 5, type: .three),
    ]
    var body: some View {
        Chart{
            ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                BarMark(x: .value("X", data[i].width))
                    .clipShape(clipShape(forIndex: i))
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("X", data[i].type))
                if i != data.count - 1 {
                    BarMark(x: .value("Separator", 0.1))
                        .foregroundStyle(.clear)
                }
            }
            RectangleMark(yEnd: 3)
                .foregroundStyle(.black.opacity(0.34))
                .blur(radius: 1)
                .clipShape(Rectangle().inset(by: 1))
                .offset(y: -1)
        }
        .chartXAxis {
            AxisMarks(values: .automatic(desiredCount: 0))
        }
        .frame(height: 50)
        .padding()
    }
    
    func clipShape(forIndex i: Int) -> UnevenRoundedRectangle {
        if i == 0 {
            return UnevenRoundedRectangle(topLeadingRadius: 5, bottomLeadingRadius: 5)
        } else if i == data.count - 1 {
            return UnevenRoundedRectangle(bottomTrailingRadius: 5, topTrailingRadius: 5)
        } else {
            return UnevenRoundedRectangle()
        }
    }
}

enum FooType: String, Plottable {
    case one, two, three
}

struct Foo: Hashable {
    let width: Double
    let type: FooType
}
```

[image]